# setValue is applying a wrong value to the Input

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I'm having very weird problem with the `setValue` command in nightwatch.

Before the `setValue`  I do have `perform` command with a callback in which I'm assigning a new value to a variable.

However `setValue` is seeing the original/first value of the variable as `inputValue`, but the updated one in the `callback`.

Here is an example:

```
module.exports = {
    'myTest': function (browser) {
        let user = {
            'test': 'test',
            'emailAddress': 'email@dsa.ds'
        }

    browser
        .url('https://url.com/sign-up')
        .useCss().waitForElementVisible('#signup-form')
        .perform(function (done) {
            createNewUserEmail()
            console.log(user.emailAddress); // theNewUser@dassdsadas.dsa
            done();
        })
        .perform(function (done) { // just to double check what value of the user emailAddress I do have before  setValue()
            console.log(user.emailAddress); // theNewUser@dassdsadas.dsa
            done();
        })
        .setValue('#EmailAddress', user.emailAddress /* email@dsa.ds */, function () {
            console.log(user.emailAddress) // theNewUser@dassdsadas.dsa
        })
        .pause(5000)
        .end();

    function createNewUserEmail() {
        user.emailAddress = 'theNewUser@dassdsadas.dsa'
        // Originally I'm using a promise but nothing is chaning and still have the same result
    }
    }
};
```

Is it a bug in **nightwatch** or I'm not understanding how it's suppose to work?

I can fix the problem by updating the second `perform` to:

```
.perform(function (browser, done) {
            browser.setValue('#EmailAddress', user.emailAddress)
            console.log(user);
            console.log(user.emailAddress);
            done();
        })
```

but this is a workaround in my understanding.

I checked the [Understanding the Command Queue](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue) but the updating of the variable is happening in the `perform`. As well the callback of the `setValue` is seeing the right value

Comment: I believe this is one of the best explanation of the issue I had written by Lukasz Czyzykowski: http://czyzykowski.com/posts/nightwatch-gotcha.html

Answer (score 0):

`.setValue` and `user.emailAddress` is getting loaded into the command queue before the code within the performs is loaded.

Using `.setValue` within a perform block should ensure it loads the newly defined `user.emailAddress`.